# Is there a function in Excel that is similar to Ruby's Split Method?

Tags: excel, vba

Given the following string:

```
"Data 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006"
```

I would like to be able to take the string and put the data in 10 separate columns in an excel spreadsheet. I am working on a user defined function, but it's not quite working yet.

Has anyone already solved this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Highlight your range that has the string you want to split
2. Go to the data tab
3. Select Text to Columns
4. Set the delimiter to a space

You can also do it with a formula: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/591897-text-to-columns-but-using-a-formula.html

Or use the code creamyegg posted.

Comment: + 1 for suggesting Text To Columns :)

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is yes. There is a VBA `Split()` function you can use which returns a variant array. The below would put your example string in cells `A1:I1` of the active worksheet:

```
Dim varArray As Variant

varArray = Split("Data 1998 1999 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006", " ")

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, UBound(varArray))).Value = varArray
```